# PHP Laravel Trix wysiwyg how to display content from db

Tags: php, laravel, wysiwyg, trix

Im using laravel 6.0 and have issue with Trix wysiwyg. How to get value to trix editor. The problem is not how to pass it to the view, where I using trix, the problem is how to display it - for example here iam geting content (title) by "value":

```
Title: </br><input type="text" id='title' name='title' value="{{$article->title}}"></br>
```

but how to $article->title in Trix, to have chance to edit it? :)

```
 @trix(\App\Article::class, 'title')
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Te7a-Houdini/laravel-trix#render-trix-for-existing-model) help you?

Answer (score 0):

just put a value to the hidden input of trix

```
 <input id="short_desc" type="hidden" name="product_short_description" value="{{ $product->product_short_description ?? "" }}" >
 <trix-editor input="short_desc" placeholder="Product short description"></trix-editor
```